# Versioning Projects in Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am currently working on Phase 1 of my project and all files are checked into Visual Source safe. How do I version this project as phase 1.

I know if it is a single file we can roll back changes etc.

After I start working on Phase 2. I should be able to get the phase I project and make any changes as required.

Please help

Comment: Do people really still use VSS for new projects?  There are better options available.

Comment: Second Kibbee's remark (+1).  Visual Source Safe is a very poor choice for version control for various reasons found at this link: http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSS has a feature called "Share and Pin". It is the closest thing it has to branching. I've found it to take a long time, slows down access later on, and hard to work with.

But I would suggest starting by looking in the help for that topic.

[Introducing Visual SourceSafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h0544kx%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[How to: Share and Branch a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dw155ey%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make changes to both Phase 1 and Phase 2, your only option is to make a copy of the entire project.

If you don't need to go back and make changes to Phase 1 and will only ever need to get the code for it, you can use a label.